# Convert nested Python dictionary to a list of lists

Tags: python, decision-tree

I have seen several examples here, but none answered this question with clarity and precision. How would I convert this nested dictionary:

```
d = {0: {0: 0, 1: {1: {0: 0, 1: 1}}}}
```

to a list of lists so that the result would be:

```
[0, 0, [1, 0, 1]]
```

I have tried, but it just keeps escaping me. It evens feels like I am missing something, but probably not.

Comment: Can you explain how that nested dict relates to the nested list? It really clarify the problem if it wasn't only ones and zeros. It's hard to tell whether you want the keys, values, or some mix. The nesting is also not clear — the dict is nested three deep, but the list is only nested two deep.

Comment: There are only three numeric values in the dictionary, so it's not clear how you end up with 5 in the nested list. Could you provide some more details please.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you wanted to print a list of keys from the dictionary(since you have 5 keys), please specify if the list is made of keys, because if you do not specify that, then the question looks a bit vague.

I will answer assuming that you wanted to print keys.

for that, you can just iterate through all inner dictionaries and add all the keys to a list, and finally print the list.